# Modal operator to: (A) Create surface (B) create vertex on surface

Tags: scripting, snapping, coordinates, draw-mode

Would like to find some tutorial and documents for blender 290
about python vectors, raycast and modal.

i am doing my best trying to create this tool,
right now i can only create new object, add them some vertex and edges but i am really far from using a modal and snap the coordinates on the surface..

i would like to change quite often the "Target plane shape",
So i plan to have the event of the keyboard change from mode A to mode B
But i also worried about the existing shortcut , they fight with the modal?

Surface_target A  ( we can change this with every drawing A)

Sequence_Edges B  ( the edge you drawn remain there)

[image]

Thank you for your time

EDIT:
To "Draw" using the mouse, require the use of a modal to get the events of the mouse, and read the position and the clicks.
Making a modal and a tool is harder than i thought.

I posted a working basis to use a UITool and a modal to get and update the mouse events .
https://blenderartists.org/t/event-leftmouse-pressed-disturbed-by-tool-selection/1270882
Once understand the behaviour you can add some of the function of the template like,
Ray cast modal, to get the 3D location of the mouse .

Comment: _`Text Editor > Templates > Python > Operator View3D Modal Raycast`_ is a good starting point.

Comment: Hi, yes i know that blender have preset but learning at reverse is pretty hard.
I have to search almost every line and try understanding from answer and api.
And i start reading and studyng the pages that refer to the line ... sometimes ending in a loop of pages XD. its like darksoul .

Comment: To "Draw" using the mouse, require the use of a modal to get the events of the mouse, and read the position and the clicks.
Making a modal and a tool is harder than i thought.

I posted a working basis to use a UITool and a modal to get and update the mouse events .
https://blenderartists.org/t/event-leftmouse-pressed-disturbed-by-tool-selection/1270882
Once understand the behaviour you can add some of the function of the template like, 
Ray cast modal, to get the 3D location of the mouse .

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/150314/19156

Comment: Thanks, this is quite a journey...  Property panels operators tool..... somehow i made something, thanks for links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This was really complex for me, its a bit messy but i share it anyway.
Hope will help someonelse XD
Its just a script, you paste it in you script and run.
A tool and a panel will appear in your 3Dview, follow instruction for play .

https://mega.nz/file/wz4VCaaJ#7TxFvZqyeQZOFy7syu56As5RionvmfhYuTs0JvhZ8h8