# Click on mesh coordinates in python API

Tags: python, coordinates, mouse

Is there a way to get the exact coordinates where you click on a mesh in python code? Faces can be big, so the vertices are not really good enough.

Comment: when you leftpress somewhere the 3d cursor moves to that place, and it snaps to suface, so you can get the 3d cursor location.

Comment: That sounds perfect, but I'm really sure what the "3d curser" is. I can't see it in the view. Do you know how toI access it in python?

Comment: in 2.8 it is bpy.context.scene.cursor.location, see documentation for current python api:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150267/how-to-move-object-while-tracking-to-mouse-cursor-with-a-modal-operator/150314#150314